# Batch script to move files from a local directory to a particular ftp location

Tags: batch-file

Currently I have a batch script which backups my database and store the backup file in a particular local directory, for e.g. say, C:\Backups\backup-30-07-2011.bak (the backup files will be created with the current date)..

Now, I need a BATCH script to move ONLY the backup files which are created on the current date to a FTP location. 
Hence my batch script must:
(1) Connect to a ftp site with its username and password
(2) Move the file of current date to the specified ftp location..
can anyone help me on this batch script.

Thanks..

Comment: http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm#delete

Answer (score 1):

More info about ftp here: http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm
Example of batchscript, which makes copy of backup:

```
@echo off
    :: Set filename and path
    :: %date:.=-% mean replace dots '.' to '-' in the variable's value  (31.07.2011)
    :: More info: set /?
    set "fileName=backup-%date:.=-%.bak"
    :: There mustn't be slash in end. "C:\Backups\" is wrong, "C:\Backups" is right
    set "filePath=C:\Backups"
    set "ftpFilePath=somepath"

    :: there must be ftp's IP & port
    set "ftpIP=127.0.0.1"
    set "ftpPort=21"

    :: replace with your own username & password
    set "username=username"
    set "password=password"

    :: Write commands in file
    :: Open server
    echo o %ftpIP% %ftpPort%>ftpcmds
    :: Say your name & password. If you have no password - just do not change   these lines
    echo %username%>>ftpcmds
    echo %password%>>ftpcmds
    :: We send binary data, yep?
    echo binary>>ftpcmds
    :: Change ftp path
    echo cd %ftpFilePath%>>ftpcmds
    :: Change local path
    echo lcd "%filePath%">>ftpcmds
    :: Yeah, we can send file
    echo send %fileName%>>ftpcmds
    :: Bye = disconnect + quit
    echo bye>>ftpcmds

    :: Run ftp-client. More info: ftp --help
    :: Delete '>nul' if you want see output of ftp
    ftp -s:ftpcmds>nul
exit /b
```

If you want you can add command to delete original file (put it before 'exit /b'):

```
del /s/q %filePath%\%fileName%>nul
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...
As you said, now the file is copied to the specified FTP location..
But,
On investigating the new file (copied file) in FTP, the size is of ZERO BYTES!!!
Which means, the file is not copied properly, but only the file is created in the specified location...

Can you say what I did wrong with my batch script..

Comment: I have pasted my script below:
set "fileName=sample.compressed"
set "filePath=C:\Backups"
set "ftpFilePath=ftp_address"

set "ftpAddress=ftp_ip_address"
set "ftpPort=21"

set "username=ftp_username"
set "password=ftp_password"

echo o %ftpAddress% %ftpPort%>ftpcmds
echo %username%>>ftpcmds
echo %password%>>ftpcmds
echo binary>>ftpcmds
echo cd %ftpFilePath%>>ftpcmds
echo lcd "%filePath%">>ftpcmds
echo send %fileName%>>ftpcmds
echo bye>>ftpcmds
ftp -s:ftpcmds
exit

Comment: Try to rewrite last command ('ftp -s:ftpcmds') as 'ftp -s:ftpcmds>ftp.log' and post file 'ftp.log' here

Comment: Hi, Thanks... I found issue with my firewall.. after adding exception rule, I can upload the files successfully. Thanks again...

Comment: If there no problems more, can you mark my answer as right answer?